# iCalendar ATTENDEE

Tags: outlook, icalendar, vcalendar

Hi is it possible to specify a 'nickname' as the ATTENDEE in Vcalendar . so that instead of the email address appearing in the email 'required' field it would display a more friendly name ? 
thanks for any help

Mick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, easily via the CN parameter:

```
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=Test User:MAILTO:test.user@somewhere.com
```

See also: http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/attendee.html

Comment: Thanks and the link is very helpful !

Cheers