# DDay iCal - adding an Attendee

Tags: asp.net-mvc, icalendar, dday

How does one add required/optional attendees + organizer(s) to an iCal event?

I'm using the excellent DDay library, and would love to be able to also [add a CN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655041/icalendar-attendee), but haven't found any examples in the [documentation](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/Documentation/), the downloaded examples or elsewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got a solution. Not very neat but its working for me.

```
iCalendar calendar = new iCalendar();
calendar.Method = "PUBLISH";

Event evt = calendar.Create<Event>();

var attendes = new List<IAttendee>();
//required attendee
IAttendee attendee1 = new DDay.iCal.Attendee("MAILTO:myid@gmail.com")
{
    CommonName = "Naveen Jose",
    Role = "REQ-PARTICIPANT"
};
attendes.Add(attendee1);
//optional attendee
IAttendee attendee2 = new DDay.iCal.Attendee("MAILTO:someid@codovations.com")
{
    CommonName = "Noah Naveen",
    Role = "OPT-PARTICIPANT"
};
attendes.Add(attendee2);
if (attendes != null && attendes.Count > 0)
{
    evt.Attendees = attendes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use RSVP = true to prompt for a reply from the attendee

```
IAttendee attendee1 = new DDay.iCal.Attendee("MAILTO:myid@gmail.com")
{
    CommonName = "Naveen Jose",
    Role = "REQ-PARTICIPANT",
    RSVP = true
};
```