# How can I expose my calendar data to outlook calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook, icalendar

I have an asp.net mvc app with SQL server backend and I have one page that stores calendar event info( database has calendar table and event table with foreign key to calendar table ).  How can I expose that info for google calendar or outlook calendars users to subscribe to a calendar?

Comment: via iCal you can achieve this easily.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this might be an ActionResult returning an .ical format calendar which can be subscribed in almost any mail client. You can use [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) for creating the iCalendar. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8253195/2779582) is some example code about it. Good luck.